# Python Firebase unread message stream

Tags: python, firebase

I have this question that partially has to do with firebase. I am currently using a mixed python firebase library that supports a stream.
I currently have a stream on `/unread_messages/`, so each time an unread message is placed in firebase, the `unread_message_handler()` will do something.

```
stream = FIREBASE.child('/unread_messages/').stream(unread_message_handler)
```

And the handler

```
def unread_message_handler(stream):

    for data in stream:
        if data['path'] == '/':
            # Multi-message node
            messages = data['data'] or []
            for message_id in messages:
                if messages[message_id] is not None:
                    send_notification(message_id, messages[message_id])
        else:
            # Single-message node
            if data['data'] is not None:
               send_notification(data['path'], data['data'])
```

Problem is: I don't want to send a notification directly when an unread message is placed. I would like to wait 10 seconds, see if that particular message is still in `/unread_messages/` and if it is, send a notification.

Sending it directly is easy, That its doing already, but I'm not sure how to go about waiting 10 seconds, because the stream only calls the handler on a new action, while I continuously want to check the timestamp

**EDIT**
I am using [this](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase) library for streaming

Comment: Can you link to the docs for whichever library you're using?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Sure, I put it in the edit

Answer (score 0):

What about putting a `timestamp` value to the message data. Then when a message is added, you can read it with its `timestamp`, and set a `10 seconds delayed call` using the `timestamp` to another function, which will check in the Firebase database if the message is still unread.

Comment: The message data already has a `date` attribute. I thought about a delayed call too, but was not sure how to go about it. The stream basically handles the messages that are coming in right now (a message is basically directly an unread message). So if  I don't handle the message right away, because I have to wait 10 seconds, how would that go? Is it better to start a different process to scan all the `unread_messages` continuously?

Answer (score 0):

The library you are using spawns a Python thread when you call `stream()`, here: https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/blob/master/pyrebase/pyrebase.py#L288

That thread then invokes your callback.  It's not clear from your question what your main thread does after it calls `stream()`, but basically what you can do is to set a timer to wake up your main thread 10 seconds after each message is received in the stream thread, or just poll in your main thread every 10 seconds.